# how do you get this.form.submit() to submit as a GET for a Ajax.BeginForm() form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, request, addeventlistener

I have a view that updates a partial view on a get request but when I try to add eventlisteners using vanilla JS and this.form.submit() it's submitting as a post request which is reloading the page and returning just the partial view instead of an ajax request.

Here's my code:

```
<body style="overflow-x:hidden !important;">
<h6>Activity Management</h6>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("getActivityManagementTwoActivities", "CallCenter", new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod= "Get", UpdateTargetId= "activitiesForPartial"}))
{
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="float:right;">
            <div class="dateWrapper">@{ Html.RenderPartial("_DateFilter"); } </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 8px;">
        <div class="col-md-3 ActivityManagementTwoHeader" style="font-size:12px; font-weight: bold">
            Displaying Results 5 of 5
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Items per page:
            @Html.DropDownList("results", new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "25", Text= "25"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "50", Text= "50"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "100", Text= "100"},
                })
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select id="test2222">
                <option>Filter</option>
                <option>test</option>
            </select>
            <select>
                <option>Sort</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
}

    <div id="activitiesForPartial">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ActivityManagementCollapseComponent", Model);}
    </div>
<script>
//this part is failing to update as an AJAX 
    document.getElementById("test2222").addEventListener("change", function () {
        alert("test");
        this.form.submit(); 
    })
</script>
```

The problem is the request is being sent as a POST which just wants to reload the page and only return a partial view. I just want to update the partial view AJAXingly without reloading the page.

My button works. The Submit works just fine.

Comment: Form.submit() doesn’t use Ajax, you would need to prevent the default behaviour and handle that part with your own code.

Comment: oh I see thanks. I ended up going with Jquery  get closest form and .trigger submit but I don't like using jquery. I'm still interested in a vanilla JS way